# THREEJS - Make meshes perpendicular to the Sphere face it's sitting on

Tags: three.js, normals

```js
// THREEJS RELATED VARIABLES

var scene, camera, renderer, container, controls, raycaster, sphere_radius, HEIGHT, WIDTH;

//INIT THREE JS, SCREEN AND MOUSE EVENTS

function createScene() {

 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;

 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000);

 camera.position.x = 0;
 camera.position.z = 1500;
 camera.position.y = 0;

 // ORBIT CAMERA
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
 controls.update();

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
 renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 container = document.getElementById('world');
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 
}
function randomSpherePoint(x0,y0,z0,radius){
   var u = Math.random();
   var v = Math.random();
   var theta = 2 * Math.PI * u;
   var phi = Math.acos(2 * v - 1);
   var x = x0 + (radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta));
   var y = y0 + (radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta));
   var z = z0 + (radius * Math.cos(phi));
   return [x,y,z];
}

Island = function(){
 this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
 // number of cubes
 this.nLands = 30;
 this.lands = [];

 
 for(var i = 0; i < this.nLands; i++){
  var c = new Land();
  this.lands.push(c);
    
  var stepAngle = Math.PI*2 * Math.random();
  var a = stepAngle*i;
  var h = sphere_radius;

  var randPos = randomSpherePoint(0,0,0,sphere_radius);
  c.mesh.position.y = randPos[1];
  c.mesh.position.x = randPos[0];
  c.mesh.position.z = randPos[2];


  this.mesh.add(c.mesh);
 }
}

Land = function(){
 this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
 this.mesh.name = "land";


 var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 2, 2, 50, 64 );

 var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x59332e});

 var m = new THREE.Mesh(geom.clone(), mat);
 m.position.x = 0;
 m.position.y = Math.random()*2;
 m.position.z = Math.random()*10;
 this.mesh.add(m);
}



Sea = function(){
 // radius top, radius bottom, height, number of segments on the radius, number of segments vertically
 sphere_radius = 300;
 var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphere_radius,sphere_radius,32,32);


 var mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
  transparent:true,
  opacity:.5,
  flatShading:true,
 });
 this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
 this.mesh.name = "sea";
}

// 3D Models
var sea;

function createSea(){
 sea = new Sea();
 sea.mesh.position.y = 0;
 scene.add(sea.mesh);
}


function createIsland(){
 island = new Island();
 island.mesh.position.y = 0;
 scene.add(island.mesh);
}

function loop(){ 

 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 
}

function init(event){

 createScene();
 createSea();
 createIsland();
 loop();
}


window.addEventListener('load', init, false);


function handleWindowResize() {
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);
```

```css
html, body {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="world"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r94/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Related codepen:
https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/zLymrz

On three.js, i have a bunch of `cylinders` added to random positions on the exterior of `sphere`.

The issue im having now is that they're all facing straight up to the z-axis.

Im thinking that what i should do is to make the cylinder `lookAt` the angle of where the cylinder intersects the sphere. But im not sure how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Heres a image that describes the situation.

[image]

Comment: have you tried using `lookAt` with each cylinder and looking at the center of the the sphere?

Comment: so the center of the sphere is `0,0,0`, but when i apply those values to the cylinder's `lookAt`, they're not looking at the center of the sphere:

https://imgur.com/a/O9XirH4

Comment: looks like you need to rotate your cylinders `???.rotation.x = Math.PI *.5`

Comment: OH RIGHT. i was assuming that the `lookAt` was occuring from long side of the cylinders. i applied the  rotation to the geometry by doing so :

`land_geom.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI/2)); `

it works now and i've updated the codepen. Thank you!